# Remove everything from array after second \n

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string

I have an array where need to remove everything after the second \n

For example `numbers = ['2.05\n1.68\n2.70\n1.41\n4.70\n22.0\n5.60\n']`

and need to remove everything after **1.68\n**

Result need to be
`numbers = ['2.05\n1.68\n']`

Tried with rsplit but I really don't understand how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract the part of the numbers string you're interested in:

```py
import re

def extract(num_string):
    match = re.match(r'.+\n.+\n', num_string)
    return match.group() if match else ''

numbers = ['2.05\n1.68\n2.70\n1.41\n4.70\n22.0\n5.60\n']
result = [extract(s) for s in numbers]
```

gives

```
['2.05\n1.68\n']
```

This will work for any list of strings.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much! 
If I want to do from behind to have `22.0\n5.60\n` what should I do?

Comment: @MareS992 you can use `re.search(r'.+\n.+\n$', num_string)` for that

Comment: This returns  an empty array

`def extract(num_string):
    match = re.search(r'.+\n.+\n$', num_string)
    return match.group() if match else ''`

Comment: Are you calling it in the same way? i.e. `[extract(s) for s in numbers]` and not something like `extract(numbers)`

Comment: Very strange. What does `re.search(r'.+\n.+\n$', '2.05\n1.68\n2.70\n1.41\n4.70\n22.0\n5.60\n')` return?

Comment: Now return `['22.0\n5.60\n']` but in another array where I try this, return an empty array.

Comment: you mean you have other data?

Comment: Yes, I have other data. Actually scrape something and the array is long and now needs to trim from behind. The first answer works perfectly, but when trying to trim from behind not work.

Comment: You'll have to show that data with which it doesn't work

Comment: I have edited the question. Now I see the last value doesn't have \n tag. What to do in this case?

Comment: Please don't copy my answer into your question, that just creates confusion. To make the final linebreak optional, you can use the pattern `r'.+\n.+\n?$'`